# Beautifulsoup - Issue when appending scraped results to CSV file

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, tags

HTML:

```
<div class="job-result-logo-title">
   <div class="job-result-logo">
      <a href="/Recruiters/SQS-Ireland-5673.aspx"><img alt="SQS Ireland" src="/Logos/SQS-Ireland-small-5673.gif"></a>
   </div>
   <div class="job-result-title">
      <h2 itemprop="title"><a href="/Jobs/QA-Analyst-8148774.aspx">QA Analyst</a>
      </h2>
      <h3 itemprop="name">
         <a itemprop="hiringOrganization" itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/Organization" href="/Recruiters/SQS-Ireland-5673.aspx">SQS Ireland</a>
      </h3>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="job-result-overview" style="display: ">
   <ul class="job-overview">
      <li itemprop="baseSalary" class="salary">Negotiable</li>
      <li itemprop="datePosted" class="updated-time">Updated 17/03/2018</li>
      <li itemprop="jobLocation" class="location">
         <a href="/Jobs/Dublin-City-Centre/">Dublin City Centre</a>
         <span>&nbsp;/</span>                                            <a href="/Jobs/Dublin-South/">Dublin South</a>
         <span>&nbsp;/</span>                                            <a href="/Jobs/Dublin-North/">Dublin North</a>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

My Code:

```
def find_data(source):
    for a in source.find_all('div', class_='job-result-title'):
        job_info = a.find('h2').find('a')
        company_name = a.find('h3').find('a').get_text()
        url = job_info['href']
        full_url = base_url + url
        role = job_info.get_text()
    for ul in source.find_all('ul', class_='job-overview'):
        date = ul.find('li',class_='updated-time').get_text().replace('Updated','').strip()
    append_data("data.csv", company_name, role, full_url, date)
```

I have tried too many alternatives to this code and also tried looking for a similar answer here, but no luck, I always keep getting the same date from this line of code and I'm not sure why it is not iterating over all the same tags containing the dates for each one:

```
<li itemprop="datePosted" class="updated-time">Updated 17/03/2018</li>
```

Comment: you append data only after the loops, you have to put addition(append_data function) to csv inside the loop(s)

Comment: What is the parent of `<div class="job-result-logo-title">`? what page on https://www.irishjobs.ie/?

Comment: Hi @TigerTV.ru, I'm getting everything from here:
https://www.irishjobs.ie/ShowResults.aspx?Keywords=test&Location=102&Category=3&Recruiter=All&SortBy=MostRecent&PerPage=100

Comment: You need one loop, `for a in source.find_all('div', class_='module-content'):` find info inside the loop and append data for every iteration.

Comment: Your title is a bit misleading, please change it.

Comment: Thanks @TigerTV.ru your solution did the trick, I was not iterating from the parent div, that was the main issue.

Comment: Thanks @KeyurPotdar, your answer also worked but I was going for a simpler answer and not trying to deviate too much from original code. I'm still learning and your comments are really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not saving the values that you are finding inside the `for` loop. That's why when you write into a CSV file, you are getting the last value for all the variables.

You need to save all the values in lists, and then write them in the CSV.

Code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://www.irishjobs.ie/ShowResults.aspx?Keywords=test&Location=102&Category=3&Recruiter=All&SortBy=MostRecent&PerPage=100')
source = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

company_name, role, full_url, date = [], [], [], []
base_url = 'https://www.irishjobs.ie'

for a in source.find_all('div', class_='job-result-title'):
    job_info = a.find('h2').find('a')
    company_name.append(a.find('h3').find('a').get_text())
    url = job_info['href']
    full_url.append(base_url + url)
    role.append(job_info.get_text())
for ul in source.find_all('ul', class_='job-overview'):
    date.append(ul.find('li',class_='updated-time').get_text().replace('Updated','').strip())

for a, b, c, d in zip(company_name, role, full_url, date):
    print(a, b, c, d)
```

Partial Output:

```
Globoforce Senior QA Automation Engineer https://www.irishjobs.ie/Jobs/Senior-QA-Automation-Engineer-8149253.aspx 17/03/2018
Globoforce Technical  Team Lead (Java) https://www.irishjobs.ie/Jobs/Technical-Team-Lead-Java-8149252.aspx 17/03/2018
Globoforce Performance Test Engineer https://www.irishjobs.ie/Jobs/Performance-Test-Engineer-8149251.aspx 17/03/2018
Globoforce Senior Front End Developer https://www.irishjobs.ie/Jobs/Senior-Front-End-Developer-8149249.aspx 17/03/2018
Synchronoss Technologies Lead iOS Swift  Developer Enterprise Agile https://www.irishjobs.ie/Jobs/Lead-iOS-Swift-Developer-Enterprise-8149248.aspx 17/03/2018
Computer Futures .NET Engineer Front End Developer https://www.irishjobs.ie/Jobs/NET-Engineer-Front-End-Developer-8149244.aspx 17/03/2018
Computer Futures .NET Developer C# ASP.NET Core https://www.irishjobs.ie/Jobs/NET-Developer-CSharp-ASP-NET-8149241.aspx 17/03/2018
Computer Futures Senior C# Developer TDD DDD https://www.irishjobs.ie/Jobs/Senior-CSharp-Developer-TDD-DDD-8149240.aspx 17/03/2018
```

You just need to write the values in the CSV instead of `print(a,b,c,d)`.